# how prevent dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to repeat my segment select?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have table contains custom cells contain uisegment 
The problem is when select any item in uisegment and scroll down in the table view it change the selection in uisegment in the cells down on table

almost cell 1 like 11 and 2 like 12

It related to dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and my question is what is the best way to solve it ?

[image]

```
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let item = self.cells.items[indexPath.row]

    if let cellHedaer: TcPationQuestionHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderItem") as? TcPationQuestionHeader {
        cellHedaer.setCell(Results.Questions[indexPath.row/2 ])

        if item as? SwiftyAccordionCells.HeaderItem != nil {
            let cellItem: TcPationQuestionItem = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Item") as! TcPationQuestionItem

            cellItem.setCell(Results.Questions[indexPath.row/2])

            return cellItem
        }

        cellHedaer.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        return cellHedaer
    }
```

Comment: Cells get reused, so if you apply a state to cell 1, and it gets reused as cell 11, cell 11 will have the same state. To fix this, keep track in your viewController or dataSource which cells/objects should have a certain state, and apply this state in cellForRowAtIndexPath. This makes sure that every cell will apply its own correct state, instead of reusing a state from a previous cell.

Comment: can please explain more or give me a example , just set it as answer to can descripe in details

Comment: What I can conclude from your code is that setCell() sets the content of the cell, right? In addition to doing this, you also want to set the correct state for the UISegment. If you set no state for the UISement, the previously used state will be used (as that's what cell reuse does). So if I set the first segment control to 'No', and I scroll down and the cell gets reused, this cell will display 'No' in its segment control. So what you want to do is keep track in your viewController (or Question/Results object) which answer is given, and apply this answer as state to your UISegment

Comment: yeah it solve my problem thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 major problems in your code:

1. You shouldn't keep the state inside UI. Every accessing data from UI
   is a big mistake. You should keep selection inside model. The easiest way is to keep array var inside controller.
2. In some cases you will call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` 2 times. That shouldn't happen too.

Don't forget the implementation of `cellForRow` is connected to `numberOfRowsAtIndexPath` and `numberOfSections`. If you want to more detailed help paste here these 2 functions.

Comment: thanks for notice I will consider it the problem is solved